# I need to count students by very hard parameter, and idk how to do it

Tags: c#, ms-access

on the internet i find only very few info about count in ms access
there is query string

```
"SELECT students.Student FROM specialty INNER JOIN (groups INNER JOIN
((mark INNER JOIN students ON mark.idstudent = students.IDstudent)
INNER JOIN miss ON students.IDstudent = miss.IDstudent)
ON(groups.IDgroup = students.IDgroup) AND(groups.IDgroup = miss.IDgroup))
ON specialty.IDspecialty = groups.IDspecialty WHERE specialty.Name =
'" + DateFind.otdel + "' GROUP BY students.Student"
```

what does it - it selects all students with misses, 2, non-admission to lessons. And i need to count amount of students with that parameters.

and i tried to do something with counting via adding

```
SELECT COUNT(student) FROM students.student WHERE
```

and it does nothing. Idk how to work with count so help pls, i rly checked on internet and there was only simple queries like count by 1 field without any innerjoins and etc.

Comment: Your SQL code is very poorly formatted and is hard to read; you need to clean that up. It must have been auto-generated with all the `ON` clauses at the bottom of the code. The joins don't make sense because the `mark` table is not joined back to any other table. You need to post some sample input data and how you are expecting the results.

Comment: Also. You are vulnerable to SQL injection by using string concatenation instead of using variables.

Comment: db used in local college program, which is located on local unconnected to internet pc. So i dont worry about injections @tim-jarosz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your posted query works, then wrap this as a *subquery*:

```
"Select Count(*) From (SELECT students.Student FROM specialty INNER JOIN (groups INNER JOIN
((mark INNER JOIN students ON mark.idstudent = students.IDstudent)
INNER JOIN miss ON students.IDstudent = miss.IDstudent)
ON (groups.IDgroup = students.IDgroup) AND (groups.IDgroup = miss.IDgroup))
ON specialty.IDspecialty = groups.IDspecialty WHERE specialty.Name =
'" + DateFind.otdel + "' GROUP BY students.Student) As T"
```